# Hg strip but keep newly tracked / removed files

Tags: mercurial, changeset

I usually use `hg strip -k` to remove some changesets before pushing modified code to a remote repository. The problem with this command is that every file that was processed with `hg add/remove` is no longer in Added/Removed list

Is there any command that will remove changesets, will keep the changes and will also keep the added/removed files?

Comment: I don;t have time for a full answer but Mercurial Queues will allow you to convert a changeset to a patch so it is removed as a changset but you still have the changes to the files still there, you can edit them etc and then re-apply the patch.

Comment: I don't understand why you would use `strip` this way. As mentioned in an answer, phases seems much more appropriate. But also you can tell `hg push` to only push specific revisions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you do not want to push the latest changeset(s) only: then the best solution is to change their phase from draft or public to secret: `hg phase --force --secret --revXXX` where XXX is the earliest of those changesets. This has the advantage that they never leave your local repository but simply won't be pushed until you change their phase back to draft or public.

Generally: public > draft > secret. Public changesets are immutable, drafts are mutable but shared, secret ones mutable and not shared. Drafts might change to public on push when pushed to a publishing repository (default). You might want to read up on phases in general and consider making your default commit phase secret so that you need to change phase for those commits you want to push: [Phases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases)

If however you need to remove changesets in the middle of a commit series, just use strip as you are used to. It will put the whole commit into a bundle which can be re-imported into the repository at a later time using `hg unbundle BUNDLE_FILENAME`. It won't keep the commits in the repository though, thus remember the filenames or check the bundle filenames contents later using `hg incoming BUNDLE_FILENAME`. (Note: should you use the evolve extension you need the --bundle parameter with strip)

If you are uncomfortable with that and rather want 'normal' patch files, use `hg export XXX > file_XXX.patch` (XXX being a revision) prior to stripping on the changesets you do not want to share.

Comment: Note that `--bundle` becomes available only if you have the evolve extension installed; it is the default behavior without evolve.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that (anymore). I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: It seems that hg unbundle BUNDLE_FILENAME also brings back changesets.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is to use `hg shelve` to temporarily shelve your changes and to use `hg unshelve` to restore them afterwards. You may have to enable the built-in shelve extension via an entry in your `.hgrc` first, e.g.:

```
[extensions]
shelve=
```

Note that the better solution is, as indicated in the other response, to not use `hg strip` in the first place, but to use phases to indicate which commits you don't want to push. Using `hg strip` here is a bit like using a sledgehammer to crack open an egg. I've still added my response, because there are other uses for `hg strip` where having a way to keep the current changes is useful, but the other one is really the "right" response for this use case.

Comment: Note that shelve very useful if you have a bit of uncommitted work (then it might be the tool of choice), but not if you have already committed your work or even a sequence of commits.which you want to withhold.

Comment: Yup. It's an alternative to the `--keep` option of strip, not to keeping commits secret.

Comment: Note that the TortoiseHG GUI also has built in shelving capabilities.